# Can't get $_POST to work

Tags: php, forms, post

I'm trying to assign values to the array using this form (in account.html):

```
<form name="register" action="register.php" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username:</label> <input type="text" name="username"                class="textb" maxlength="30"/><br /><br>
    Password  :  <input type="password" name="password1" class="textb"/><br /><br>
    Re-Type Password: <input type="password" name="password2" class="textb"/><br /><br>

    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="Create Account" value="Create Account" class="texta" />
</form>
```

But when I try to call them here (in register.php) :

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password1 = $_POST["password1"];
$password2 = $_POST["password2"];
```

I just get:

```
Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: password1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: password2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php on line 5
```

Can anyone shed some light as to why The form isn't posting the variables?

Here is the full register.php file:

```
<?php

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password1 = $_POST["password1"];
$password2 = $_POST["password2"];

if($password1 != $password2)
header("location:register.php");

if (strlen($username) > 30)
header("location:register.php");
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'test';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$query = "INSERT INTO members (username, password)
    VALUES ('$username', '$password1');";
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();
header('Location: index.php');

?>
```

Here is the full account.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Video for Education Log In</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
<div id="logo">
    videoedu.edu    </div>
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" class="menua">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html" class="menua">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br>
<div id="page">




<div id="content">
<h2>Create an Account. It's free and lets you share and watch streamed educational         video content.</h2>
<h3>Simply fill out the form below.....</h3>
<div class= "form">
<form name="register" action="register.php" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username:</label> <input type="text" name="username"     class="textb" maxlength="30"/><br /><br>
    Password  :  <input type="password" name="password1" class="textb"/><br />    <br>
    Re-Type Password: <input type="password" name="password2" class="textb"/>       <br /><br>      
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="Create Account" value="Create Account"             class="texta" />
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is there anything present in post at all? what are the results ig you run var_dump($_POST)? from the code you've posted, this should work fine.

Comment: are you accessing your this code `$username = $_POST["username"];
$password1 = $_POST["password1"];
$password2 = $_POST["password2"];
` in `register.php` file?

Comment: Does it work changing $_POST to $_GET and method="post" to method="get"?

Comment: Not something I have seen before but try $_REQUEST instead of $_POST and see if that does anything...

Comment: Hi guys thanks for the replies.

When I do "var_dump($_POST);" I get "array(0) { }"

$_GET also doesn't work.

Comment: var_dump( $_POST ) to see what's being sent. If nothing, I can post a lengthy answer on checking your PHP setup...

Comment: Where should I use $REQUEST? IN the form AND register.php?

Comment: Wait wait wait... before you use another method, you should fix your $_POST capabilities. What does your var_dump show???

Comment: what does var_dump($_REQUEST) says?

Comment: See my comment above, var_dump gives back "array(0) {}

Comment: Okay my bet is you have improperly set up PHP with xampp.

Comment: try throwing some id's on the inputs.

Comment: Any ideas on what settings I've done wrong with xampp? $_POST was working fine and then suddenly stopped.

Comment: Yeah you should be at least be seeing items in the $_POST array.

Answer (score 3):

I tried out your code and it is working.

Your problem is possibly here:

```
header("location:register.php");
```

If I submit the form correctly (username < 30 and password1 == password2) the POST is fine but, but if I submit with (password1 != password2) the header will redirect back to the same page (register.php) and the POST will be empty.

Try doing a

```
var_dump($_POST);
die();
```

here

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password1 = $_POST["password1"];
$password2 = $_POST["password2"];
var_dump($_POST);
die();
```

You'll see that it is working.

Also you should add more validations before connecting to DB. You should verify the $_POST for username, password1 and password2 isset and you should escape everything to avoid some common attacks like SQL Injection and XSS (cross site scripting).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... so it's empty on submit? Try adding this to the top of your php file:

```
if(empty($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']))
{ 
  $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 
}
```

Okay, now check your php.ini (\xampp\php\php.ini):

```
post_max_size = 8M
variables_order = "EGPCS"
```

You need these two rules in there. If they aren't, add them and restart xampp.

Comment: Thanks Matthew.

variables_order wasn't in my php.ini file so I inserted it and restarted xampp.

I added that block of code to the very top of register.php.

Still no change in behaviour...

Comment: Can you post your entire php controller file (the one receiving the $_POST)?

Comment: Also, go test to make sure that your other $_POST forms still work, as you said it was working elsewhere.

Comment: My other $_POST forms still work! Where can I find the controller file?

Comment: The controller file is the one that is throwing the three notices for undefined array keys. Paste that whole file so we can detect the error. Also, is the path to register.php correct on your form? Is that file sitting in the same directory as your html form?

Comment: And it's safe to assume these errors are thrown when you submit the form... You aren't just trying to load the register.php file without a form submit are you? Yep, register.php is the controller.

Comment: I've posted the full register.php file above.

I have:
    <input type="submit" name="Create Account" value="Create Account" class="texta" />

at the bottom of my form so I don't think that could be the problem.

Comment: try getting rid of the name='register' attribute on the form tag

Comment: Okay can you post the rest of the account.html file?

Comment: Okay try getting rid of all the erroneous spacing in your form.

Comment: It's just white space though, would that make a difference?

Comment: It shouldn't, but I'm not taking anything for granted. Something is fishy here...

Comment: I just tried removing the password fields from the form altogether, and when I run a var_dump in the php file it returns:

array(2) { ["username"]=> string(4) "asdf" ["Create_Account"]=> string(14) "Create Account" }

So the array is taking in something there. There must be something wrong with the passwords part of the form...

Comment: Okay now we are getting somewhere. Try wrapping the Password: and Re-Type Password in labels.

Comment: OK I've added the <label for="username"> etc for the username and 2 password fields.

When I remove the password comparison from the php file, the array gets populated with the username and both passwords, so that could be the problem somehow?

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue caused by a change in php.ini file. If you have this line in the file:
post_max_size = "10MB" (should be 8M), that could be the problem.

Some php versions can interpret 10MB as 0, thus making the array empty.

More about this issue:

- [empty-post-array](http://www.bradino.com/php/empty-post-array/)
- [php-_post-array-empty-although-phpinput-and-raw-post-data-is-available](http://getluky.net/2009/02/24/php-_post-array-empty-although-phpinput-and-raw-post-data-is-available/)

Comment: I've studied both articles and I'm a bit confused about $data = file_get_contents('php://input');

When I try to echo $data, I get nothing back, it simply doesn't appear in the notices.

Comment: If you test the example from the second article, does it still say "array(0)" when you submit the form?

Comment: And does the php.ini file have this line post_max_size = 10MB ? Or is it 8M?

Comment: When I insert the code from the 2nd article at the top of register.php I get:

Notice: Undefined index: CONTENT_TYPE in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php on line 3
CONTENT_TYPE: 
DATA:
string(0) ""
array(0) {
}

Comment: Sorry I just realised you have to run that block of code as a separate test file. My output when I run it is:

CONTENT_TYPE: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
DATA:
string(21) "name=ok&submit=submit"
array(2) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(2) "ok"
  ["submit"]=>
  string(6) "submit"
}

Comment: So the test example prints the contents of $_POST array, while your script thinks array is empty. Do you have a meta tag which defines the character encoding in your form file? <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> or similar? Could also check if your form file itself is in utf-8 encoding? Can't think of anything else.

Comment: The meta tag reads: '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />'

Would changing the character set to utf-8 make a difference?